# How do I set different value for my request mock in each different test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In my unit test I have the following `setUp` function:

```
    @patch("FrontEnd.FrontEnd.get_cname")
    def setUp(self, mock_get_cname):
        mock_requests = MagicMock()
        mock_requests.return_value.json.side_effect = return_side_effect
        mock_requests.return_value.status_code = 200
        mock_requests.return_value.text = 'ssl'
        self.requests = patch.object(requests, 'get', mock_requests)
        self.requests.start()
```

In one test I have the following:

```
    @patch("requests.get")
    def test_search_resource(self, mock_get):

        """Test for _search_resource"""

        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200
        self.fe._search_resource("hulahoop")
        self.assertTrue(mock_get.call_args,
                        call('www.example.com/cdn_resources.json?q=hulahoop',
                             auth=('user', 'password'),
                             timeout=5))
        mock_get.reset_mock()
        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 400
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
          self.fe._search_resource("hulahoop")
```

I am repeating the mock_get here although it has been patched in `setUp`, for the sole reason of being able to assign it different `status_code`. How do I assign different values to my `status_code` without patching `requests.get` again ?